# How to conditionally compile a JAR in Android?

Tags: android, gradle, build, compilation, lint

I'm trying to make a conditional build in Android Studio, where I can reduce the size of the generated APK by removing any superfluous library dependencies if they're not needed for a particular distribution.

I've got some code which roughly approximates to the following:

```
public class MyClass {

    /* Static Declarations. */
    public static final boolean USE_LIBRARY = false;

    public void doSomething() {
        // Are we using the library?    
        if(MyClass.USE_LIBRARY) {
            // Do something with the library that we'd define in my build.gradle.
            com.some.gradle.library.MyLibrary.doSomethingWithLibrary();
        }
        else {
            // Do something else.
        }
    }

}
```

If I remove `com.some.gradle.library` from my Gradle dependencies, I receive compilation errors indicating that the above code cannot be compiled. As you can see, provided that `USE_LIBRARY` remains false, we should never need to make any reference `MyLibrary`; not even upon instantiation, as it makes no reference to the imports; these are only encroached upon at runtime.

I should probably note that in practice, `USE_LIBRARY` is a programmatically generated constant pertaining to the app's `BuildConfig.java`.

Surely the compiler can determine that this code can be optimized? Is this some kind of pre-processor check that I can work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. The above approach I've taken *is* possible, provided that you can guarantee that no library code may be interacted with at runtime; this includes making sure that none of your runtime classes `extend` any parents or `implement` interfaces that are a part of the library. I was able to verify that the code had been expunged by using [ClassyShark](https://github.com/google/android-classyshark).

The "trick" is to declare the library components as `provided` for the build variant where you want to *pretend* the libraries are available to you, and as `compile` for when you wish to export the libraries.

i.e. Use two **Build Variants**, `libraryVariant` and `emptyVariant`, which programmatically switch the value of `USE_LIBRARY` via `buildConfigField 'boolean', 'USE_LIBRARY', 'X'`. Then you may define your dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
    // Actually package the library with the compiled APK.
    libraryVariantCompile  "com.some.gradle.library:-1"
    // Ignore the library; just please the linting process.
    emptyVariantProvided   "com.some.gradle.library:-1"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to make a conditional build in Android Studio, where I can reduce the size of the generated APK by removing any superfluous library dependencies if they're not needed for a particular distribution.

Step #1: Define a product flavor for that "particular distribution". For the purposes of this answer, I will call this `foo`. You will also need other product flavors for other distributions.

Step #2: Change your `compile` statement that pulls in this JAR to a `fooCompile` statement, so it will only be used on `foo` builds.

Step #3: Have one edition of `MyClass` in each of the product flavors' source sets (e.g., `src/foo/java/`), where the one in `foo` references the library, and the others do not.

Comment: This sounds very promising. I have stages 1 and 2 in place, but I wasn't aware that the third was even an option! I'll let you know how I get on, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confusing the behavior of the Java runtime and compile time processes.

During runtime, your code can be conditionally executed and a library call can be ignored, but during compile time all the code is processed.

By referencing the library at compile time, the dependency is required at compile time.

However, there is a utility called Proguard that is part of the android build system which can remove unused byte code from the apk.  Also, check @CommonsWare answer, if you aren't using the library at all in a different version then build types allow you to create a separate version of the apk without that library

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Trouble is, even proguard doesn't seem to be able to eliminate this library!